# Extjs two ajax request blocking problem

Tags: ajax, extjs, asynchronous, ajax-request

I have a problem with ajax requests. I need them to go independently not blocking each other.

The situation looks like this.
I have first ajax request which takes about 1minute and multiple other requests which are almost instantaneous. The 1minute request blocks other requests from happening. I need a way around.

Edit:
Well I get a hanging process in firebug which normally ends in 200ms. The other problem is if I abort the request it still takes same time as if I didn't aborted. A bug or am I aborting it in a wrong manner?

Base concept is like this:

1. load a store with onload event which has Ajax request to 60s script
2. I click a button that triggers another Ajax request to 200ms script
3. the second request waits for the first to end and then ends

I tried a different aproach also:

1. load a store with onload event which has Ajax request to 60s script
2. I click a button that triggers another Ajax request to 200ms script
3. abort first Ajax request

   - as expected firebug shows the request was aborted
   - the second script still takes 60s+200ms to end

Any ideas?

Comment: how it is blocking? who is blocking. browser? or server?

Comment: Please provide code, it's not really possible to help debug without any sample to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a session problem. I opened the session for both scripts and first one locked the session file for the time of it's execution. Closing the session for one of the scripts solved the problem.